# Displaying azimuth of line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, azimuth

I have drawn a series of straight lines on a map joining different locations. The lines have a single vertex at each end.  I am using the Ordnance Survey of Great Britain 1936 projection.

I now want to know the compass bearings I will have to walk to move from one location to the next.

- Is there any easy way to get QGIS to **calculate/display the azimuth of the lines I have drawn**?
- Better still is there any way to get QGIS to **actively display the azimuth of the lines as I am drawing them**?

I am aware there is an azimuth function but the syntax appears to need the input of the coordinates of the vertices on either end of the line which would be very time-consuming.

Comment: Related: [How to calculate azimuth in QGIS field calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155810/how-to-calculate-azimuth-in-qgis-field-calculator)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To display the azimuth, use the following expression

```
degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry)))
```

To make it more fancy use

```
CONCAT(format_number(degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry))), 2), '°')
```

[image]

To show the angle while digitizing, enable the advanced digitizing panel, the number next to **a** is what you are looking for.

[image]

Unfortunately, the second one uses a different origin line and rotation direction for the angle.

Comment: It doesn't use the same origin but you can add +90°for example to the label to make it coincident, no ?

Comment: You could, but I guess the compass bearing - on which the question focuses - is the number from the expression function.