# QGIS: writting an expression in geometry generator for a straight line with given azimuth

Tags: qgis, expression

How do I create lines for all points on the layer where the same radian and same length of line are representated on all points regardless of the point locations?

Comment: What is the -90° angle for? Wouldn't you just need azimuth and distance?

Comment: Yeah, your question does not make sense: azimuth **is** the angle of the line. Could you provide a screenshot of what you want to achieve?

Comment: No: -90 degrees **is** the azimuth. What do you understand an azimuth to be? Can you show us an example? See also here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/264422/88814

Comment: Edit your question and add the screenshot there.

Comment: I see: your values are in radians: 4.714 radians = 270 degrees and 1.569 rad = 90 degrees - see: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian - thus you don't have two values, only one on different units

Comment: @GeoCord For my answer to make sense, it'd be good to edit your question removing the ambiguity.

Comment: I meant editing the body of your original post. So your question can benefit others who might have the same problems, making the question as clear as possible helps in search engine results. Comments should also be considered disposable. Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange, which has a little bit different concept than traditional forums.

Comment: Understood, and appreciated. This comment solved it: make_line(start_point($geometry),project(start_point($geometry),4000000,4.714))!

Comment: @Gabriel_C. you should have the privilege to edit the question

Comment: @Babel I know, but I thought it was a good opportunity to engage a newcomer on how to best ask questions!

Comment: Thank you both! This really helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to achieve what you're looking for is the **Geometry by expression** tool. Expression:

```
make_line(start_point($geometry),project(start_point($geometry),4000000,4.714))
```

This should draw a line 4000km long, if your layer units are meters, at 270° from North. The `project` function throws a point a certain length away from your original point in a certain direction in radians.

Bear in mind that such long lines will have radically different shapes on different map projections. If you're looking for a loxodrome, you should be working in a conformal projection.

There might also be problems if your line crosses the limits of a projection so you will need to take that into account.