# Generate lines from origin to destination points in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I would like to generate lines from origin to destination points as illustrated below.
In this example, `ID` is a unique ID of each point and used as **origin** whereas `Dest` is used as **destination** from `ID`.

[image]

I found some posts which related to my question but it cannot directly solve my issue.

[Workflow for creating line features between two coordinate pairs in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15909/workflow-for-creating-line-features-between-two-coordinate-pairs-in-qgis)

[Creating lines from starting to arrival points?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34633/creating-lines-from-starting-to-arrival-points)

[QGIS: writting an expression in geometry generator for a straight line with given azimuth](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/398525/qgis-writting-an-expression-in-geometry-generator-for-a-straight-line-with-give)

I think the third post using `Geometry by expression` tool seems to be the one which solve my issue but I am not sure how to draw line from start to end points.

I do not need to use `geometry generator` if other solutions are easier and faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest is probably using QGIS expressions with [Geometry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html#hard-fa-geometry-generator-symbology) (for visualization only) or [Geometry by expressions](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) (to create actual geomtries) ([see here for details on both options](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)) with this expression:

```
make_line (
    $geometry ,
    geometry (get_feature (@layer, 'ID', "DEST"))
)
```

Using Geomtry by expression, you must repace the variable `@layer` with the name of the points layer in single quotes, e.g. `'points'` Form a layer named `points`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, visualization in sympoliby works well but I cannot generate lines using `geometry by expression`. I am using the same expressions in both methods. I specified layer name in @layer accordingly.

Comment: See updated answer: you must replace `@layer` by the name of your layer in single quotes.

Comment: Van you bei note Preise what wenn wrong? So you get an error. message? Can you Post a screenshot?

Comment: I also realized that I need to enclose layer name by single quotes. Thank you, it worked.

Comment: Sorry, did not mention single quotes in NY initial answer. Glad to hear it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you are working with a single layer `Points`, having the above attributes (`ID`, `Dest` & `Name`) and your *Point* geometries, I'd probably go for a *Virtual Layer* via the *DB Manager*; run:

```
SELECT
  a."Name" AS "Ori_Name",
  b."Name" AS "Dest_Name",
  MakeLine(a.geometry, b.geometry) AS geom
FROM
  "Points" AS a
  JOIN
  "Points" AS b
    ON a."Dest" = b."ID"
WHERE
  a."Dest" <> b."ID"
;
```

and add the result as a new layer.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use pyqgis:

```py
pointlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('pointlayer')[0] #Change pointlayer to the name of your point layer
points = {f['ID']:f.geometry().asPoint() for f in pointlayer.getFeatures()} #A dictionary of all point ID's and their points

#Create a memory line layer
newlayer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs={}&index=yes".format(pointlayer.crs().authid()), 'newLayer', 'memory')
provider = newlayer.dataProvider()

#Add new features to it
for f in pointlayer.getFeatures():
    if f['ID']!=f['Dest']: #If the origin and source ids are not the same
        newfeature = QgsFeature() #Create a new feature
        newgeometry = QgsLineString([points[f['ID']], points[f['Dest']]]) #Create a line geometry using the dictionary of ids and points
        newfeature.setGeometry(newgeometry)
        provider.addFeature(newfeature)
        
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(newlayer)
```

[image]