# Calculate azimuth angle in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, vector, latitude-longitude, azimuth

I have a few exercises to do and I can't do it at all. I am newbie to this field. 
I use QGIS 3.4.

**Exercise 1**
What is the azimuth between the starting point and the Z place?
I must write the value in sexagesimal degrees to a maximum of one decimal place
I don't know what to do.

I have this data:

```
[X = 518613,71] 
[Y = 275085,35]
[Dist_b =2304] 
[Azimuth_b = 15]
[Dist_c = 66]
[Azimuth_c = 316]
[Dist_d = 74]
```

Unfortunately I can't add the image because it's too big. I tried to solve the exercise and it gave me 130.1 degrees. But I don't know if it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Could be wrong but if sexagesimal degrees 130.1 should be 130°6' http://ghiorzi.org/sexagesi.htm

For azimuth calculation, not sure I understand your problem (sorry but lack of infos, so unclear for me) but look at [How to calculate azimuth in QGIS field calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155810/how-to-calculate-azimuth-in-qgis-field-calculator) for azimuth calculation. You will need your coordinates using WGS 84 (degrees) as from your question, one of your input point is projected (`[X = 518613,71]`, `[Y = 275085,35]`)

Comment: I apologise for the misunderstanding.
Thank you for your answer.
I searched before asking here and I couldn't solve the exercise.
Source coordinate reference system for my data is: EPSG:3844 - Pulkovo 1942 (58). I have to work in this projection.
I have only one point that was assigned to me from the attribute table. 
This is the requirement of the exercise: "What is the azimuth between the starting point and the Z place?" Or is it still unclear? :/

Comment: Or the solution is in the link sent by you and I can't handle it. I'll try again. (:

Comment: You have 1 points, 3 distances, 2 azimuths, you should be able to find the last point by doing triangulation